# Prove that a prime $p$ can be represented as the difference of two cubes if and only if it is of the form $p = 3k(k+1) + 1$ for some $k$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is a question from David Burton's *[Elementary Number Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0073383147)*,  p. 280, under "Representation of Integers as Sums of Squares."

> Prove that a prime $p$ can be represented as the difference of two cubes if and only if it is of the form $p = 3k(k+1) + 1$ for some $k$.

Comment: One observation that may be useful: The difference of two cubes is : $a^3 - b^3 = (a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$ which is always a composite number unless a=b+1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already pointed out by mathreadler, we have $a=b+1$, then:
$$p=a^2+ab+b^2=b^2+1+2b+b^2+b+b^2=3b(b+1)+1$$

So $p$ should be of the form $3k(k+1)+1$.

For the other direction, let $p = 3k(k+1)+1$. Then clearly $p=(k+1)^3-k^3$.

Comment: what about the other direction. this is an if and only proof

Comment: Thanks @user146269 for pointing out. It has been added.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p$ be a positive prime $p=x^3-y^3=(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)\Rightarrow x-y=1$ or $x^2+xy+y^2=1$.

If $x^2+xy+y^2=1$ then the prime is $2$ with the representation $2=(1)^3-(-1)^3$ and this prime has not a such form $3k(k+1)+1$ so the prime $2$ is an exception. When $x-y=1$ the asked form is get inmediately.

Reciprocally, all integer $n$ of the forme $3k^2+3k+1$ is obviously representable as a difference of two cubes because $(k+1)^3-k^3=n$ and so is  all prime $p$ of the same form.